# Can "and" tell sequences?

Tags: usage, conjunctions

I have a problem with the "and" when my friend get me this sentence:

> Students can join the debate team and learn a lot of skills.

To the best of my knowledge, "and" tells parallel meaning which the two items connected by "and" are of the same weighting. For example:

> I love Pokemon and Mario.

This should be only suggesting that I love both of them, but not implying that I prefer one to the another.

However, in the first quote, the sentence seems, to me, focusing what students can do but not how students can be benefited from the team. If I were my friend, I would have written:

> Students can join the debate team and *then/therefore* learn a lot of skills.

I think this stresses that you learn the skills from the team (which is the chronological order). But is that still OK to use "and"? I think this doesn't matter a lot in spoken English, but when it comes to written English, does it really matter?

I know in certain discourses like recipes, "and" can imply orders:

> Dice the carrots and fry them.

But is it usually fine to use "and" to tell sequences? Thanks!

Comment: Derrick seems to have a good enough grasp of the language that I would disagree, NVZ. He doesn't seem to be a learner to me, and although it was easily answerable with an internet search it is a nuance of the usage I could forgive someone for not being 100% aware of.

Comment: Whether a question belongs on a particular site depends entirely on the question and not on the person asking it. If Elisabeth II herself asked whether "Students can do X and do Y" is grammatical, we'd still tell her to take her business elsewhere. Because it is *not* a nuance, it is the most simplest thing.

Answer (score 3):

One of many definitions of "and" is:

**And** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/and)

> *conjunction*  1.2 Used to connect two clauses, the second of which refers to something that results from the first
>
> *"Don't take the movie too seriously, and you might enjoy it too."*
>   *"But the fun had gone out of it and the next day we did not travel."*

Comment: Thanks for your citation. English is my second language so it might seem too naive to you.. sorry about that.. it really helps!!! (And I'll use the website you provided above which I am not actually aware of it! Thanks!!!)

Comment: @DerrickTsang You're welcome. English is my second language, too.